# shouldAutorotate returns YES, but no rotation occurs

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to get my view controller to rotate, but I can't get it to work. I've added these two methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES; //iOS 5
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES; //iOS 6
}
```

And the second (im using ios6) is indeed getting called, but no rotation is occurring. Why is this?

Thank!

Comment: iOS6 default can rotate.Delete shouldAutorotate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also implement this on ios6:

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; 
}
```

This post was super useful for me to support both ios5 and 6:
[auto-rotation in iOS5/6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169419/auto-rotation-in-ios5-6)

Comment: ya i've got that in there as well... im going to read that link and see if it leads me anywhere.